# Samsung Galaxy S5 missing Sinhala fonts after Lollipop update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, 5.1-lollipop, fonts

I have upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S5 to Lollipop recently. Now I am unable to see any Sinhala fonts. Any fix for this?